# IF/ELSE AMPScript statement for multiple regions

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email

The AMPscript works for pulling social media icons in for the Italian region "IT". Detecting if the field is empty or not. I now have to do this condition for another 20 regions, it there a way for me to shorted the AMPScript. Not having to duplicate the statement 20 time and replacing with "DE", "GB", "FR" etc.....

```
<pre>
%%[ var @rows,@row,@Country,@Country,@CountryCode,@rowCount,@counter,@Facebook,@Twitter,@Instagram,@YouTube,@numRowsToReturn 

set @Country = AttributeValue('Country')
set @numRowsToReturn = 1 /* 0 means all */
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows('Ent.Country_Social_Links',@numRowsToReturn, 'CountryCode DESC','CountryCode',@Country) 
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows) 
if @rowCount > 0 then for @i = 1 to @rowCount do 
set @row = row(@rows, @i)

set @CountryCode = Field(@row,'CountryCode')
set @Facebook = Field(@row,'Facebook') 
set @Twitter = Field(@row,'Twitter') 
set @Instagram = Field(@row,'Instagram') 
set @YouTube = Field(@row,'YouTube')
set @Pinterest = Field(@row,'Pinterest')]%%


        %%[IF @Country =='IT' AND @CountryCode =='IT' THEN]%% 
        %%[IF EMPTY(@Facebook) THEN]%%
        %%[ELSE]%%
 <a href="%%=v(@Facebook)=%%"><img src="/lib/fe8b12747463007b7d/m/1/53f196ed-3550-430d-8084-da5eb3323e76.png" width="50" alt="FB"></a></td><td style="width:10px" width="10">
%%[ENDIF]%%
%%[IF EMPTY(@Twitter) THEN]%%
        %%[ELSE]%%
        <a href="%%=v(@Twitter)=%%"><img src="/lib/fe8b12747463007b7d/m/1/53f196ed-3550-430d-8084-da5eb3323e76.png" width="50" alt="TW"></a></td><td style="width:10px" width="10">
       
       %%[ENDIF]%%
%%[IF EMPTY(@Instagram) THEN]%%
        %%[ELSE]%%
        <a href="%%=v(@Instagram)=%%"><img src="/lib/fe8b12747463007b7d/m/1/4eb77747-0daa-43ed-b861-552dfd4fda93.png" width="50" alt="INTA"></a></td><td style="width:10px" width="10">
       
       %%[ENDIF]%%     
    %%[IF EMPTY(@YouTube) THEN]%%
        %%[ELSE]%%
        <a href="%%=v(@YouTube)=%%"><img src="/fe8b12747463007b7d/m/1/6b2e65ec-7fa8-470e-b42a-29a3f2272881.png" width="50" alt="YT"></a></td><td style="width:10px" width="10">
        %%[ENDIF]%%   
%%[IF EMPTY(@Pinterest) THEN]%%
        %%[ELSE]%%
       
        <a href="%%=v(@Pinterest)=%%"><img src="/lib/fe8b12747463007b7d/m/1/d4b4d8cd-c086-47cf-906c-8d328c6de4f4.png" width="50" alt="PIN"></a></td></tr></table></td>%%[ENDIF]%%</tr></table>
%%[ENDIF]%%
      
%%[NEXT @i ENDIF]%%





</pre>
```

Comment: Are the links stored in the DE for each country? If yes, then why are you matching with the value of Market Code again? You can just use %%=v(@Facebook)=%%

Comment: Yes the links are stored in the DE, In the distribution DE the country in IT and in the Social DE the CountryCode is IT, I have customer and partner for all in social with are different rows with diff links :|

Comment: @Factor33 - remember to mark answers as accepted, if they helped you in achieving your goal. This goes for all of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you cannot just make a lookup like mentioned in the comments.

Make a long list of all your countrycodes and use buildrowsetfromstring, then you can loop through them. You just use the field() function with "1" instead of a fieldname.

This goes into your existing loop after "Set @pinterest" as a nested loop.
Note that I changed @i to @j to avoid conflicts:

(untested but should convey the idea)

```
SET @codesAsString = 'IT,GB,DE'
SET @codesAsRowset = BuildRowsetFromString(BuildRowsetFromString(@codesAsString,',')
for @j = 1 to Rowcount(@codesAsRowset) do
    Set @row = Row(@codesAsRowset, @j)
    Set @code= Field(@row,1)

    IF @Country == @code AND @CountryCode == @code THEN]%% 

    /*....*/

    ENDIF

next @j
]%%
```